# React: How to hide element when token did not exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Current it works, but not as expected

```js
import {Routes, Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import appInfo from './app-info';
import routes from './app-routes';
import {SideNavOuterToolbar as SideNavBarLayout} from './layouts';
import {Footer} from './components';

export default function Content() {
    return (
        <SideNavBarLayout title={appInfo.title}>
            <Routes>           
                    {routes.map(({path, element}) => (
                        <Route
                            key={path}
                            path={path}
                            element={element}
                        />
                    ))}  

                <Route
                    path='*'
                    element={<Navigate to='/login'/>}
                />
            </Routes>
            <Footer>
                 © Bản quyền: FAMABOOK® 2018 - {new Date().getFullYear()} .
                {/*<br />*/}
                {/*All trademarks or registered trademarks are property of their*/}
                {/*respective owners.*/}
            </Footer>
        </SideNavBarLayout>
    );
}
```

it always show features inside even when not log in

[image]

I want hide menu if token in local storage did not exist, something like this

```js
import {Routes, Route, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import appInfo from './app-info';
import routes from './app-routes';
import {SideNavOuterToolbar as SideNavBarLayout} from './layouts';
import {Footer} from './components';

export default function Content() {
    return (
        <SideNavBarLayout title={appInfo.title}>
            <Routes>

                if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
                <>
                    {routes.map(({path, element}) => (
                        <Route
                            key={path}
                            path={path}
                            element={element}
                        />
                    ))}</>
            }else{

            }

                <Route
                    path='*'
                    element={<Navigate to='/login'/>}
                />
            </Routes>
            <Footer>
                 2018 - {new Date().getFullYear()} .
                {/*<br />*/}
                {/*All trademarks or registered trademarks are property of their*/}
                {/*respective owners.*/}
            </Footer>
        </SideNavBarLayout>
    );
}
```

How to archive that?

Comment: Can you please show `SideNavBarLayout`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&&` and render `routes` conditional using [`conditional rendering`](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

```
<Routes>
    {localStorage.getItem('token') && (  // IF THERE IS A TOKEN THEN ONLY RENDER
        <>
            {routes.map(({ path, element }) => (
                <Route key={path} path={path} element={element} />
            ))}
        </>
    )}
    <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/login' />} />
</Routes>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @James give this code a try-

```
{localStorage.getItem('token') != null || undefined ? <>
{routes.map(({path, element}) => (
                        <Route
                            key={path}
                            path={path}
                            element={element}
                        />
                    ))}</> : null }
```

Please try this code and if you still facing just lemme know.
Thanks